# how to add pagination in Django?

Tags: python, django, pagination

I want to apply pagination on my data I tried to watch lots of videos and read lots of articles but still can't solve my problem. This is my Views.

```
def car(request):
    all_products = None 
    all_category = category.get_all_category()
    categoryid = request.GET.get('category')
    if categoryid:
        all_products = Product.get_all_products_by_id(categoryid)
    else:
        all_products = Product.get_all_products()
        
    data = {}
    data['products'] = all_products  # all products
    
    data['category'] = all_category # all category
    all_products = Product.get_all_products()
    data['product'] = all_products
    ]
    return render(request, 'car.html', data)
```

as you can see I made some changes in above code but its make no diffrence

```
def car(request):
    all_products = None 
    all_category = category.get_all_category()
    categoryid = request.GET.get('category')
    if categoryid:
        all_products = Product.get_all_products_by_id(categoryid)
    else:
        all_products = Product.get_all_products()
         #pagination
    paginator = Paginator(all_products,2) **Changes**
    page_number=request.GET.get('page') **Changes**
    finaldata=paginator.get_page(page_number) **Changes**
    
    data = {'all_products':finaldata,}  **Changes**
    data['products'] = all_products #all products
   
    data['category'] = all_category #all category
    all_products = Product.get_all_products()
    data['product'] = all_products
  return render(request, 'car.html', data)
```

I want to display 4 products per page I tried to apply data limit query that work but that not a genuine approach to display data.
I read many articles and watch YouTube video. but can't find any solution. which videos and articles I watched there pagination method is totally different they use pagination with objects.all method to get all data and I used .get method to get data I think that is my problem. and second thing is that they just working with simple data to paginate but in my case it's so complicated. I tried alot please guide. I got stuck in solving a problem for 5 days now. I am convinced that I'm not a good programmer. I tried a lot but I can't succussed.

Answer (score 0):

**My problem is almost solve there is one issue. I can't get the next, previous and last option in pagination but soon I'll figure it out.**
**this is my views.py file coding**

```
def car(request):
    all_products = None 
    all_category = category.get_all_category()
    categoryid = request.GET.get('category')
    if categoryid:
        all_products = Product.get_all_products_by_id(categoryid)
    else:
        all_products = Product.get_all_products()
         #pagination
    paginator = Paginator(all_products,3)
    page_number=request.GET.get('page')
    finaldata=paginator.get_page(page_number)

    totalpage=finaldata.paginator.num_pages

    
    data = {'all_products':finaldata,
    'lastpage':totalpage,
    'totalPageList':[n+1 for n in range(totalpage)]}

    data['products'] = finaldata #all products

   
    data['category'] = all_category #all category
    all_products = Product.get_all_products()
    data['product'] = all_products
    
    return render(request, 'car.html', data)
```

**This is my html coding**
[my html file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l2cG.png)
I'm sharing html screenshot due to this error
Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

**I'm not familiar with stack overflow so I don't know what to do so I shared screenshot**

**when I find any solution for first previous and last option then soon I'll share that here**

Answer (score 0):

Based on pagination [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view-function), it would be something similar to this:
(Always explore the framework documentation, it is the best source to learn)

views.py

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.shortcuts import render

def car(request, category_id=None):
    products = Products.objects.all() 

    if category_id:
        products = Product.objects.filter(category__id=category_id)

    paginator = Paginator(products, 3)

    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    context = {
        'page_obj': page_obj
    }

    return render(request, 'car.html', context)
```

tempate.html (where you access previous and next pages, and total number of pages)

```
{% for car in page_obj %}
    {{ car.category }}<br>
    ...
{% endfor %}

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

urls.py (you want to pass category_id, if you don't it will be none)

```
path('cars/category/<int:category_id>/', views.car, name='car'),
```